# AngularFire simple login

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebasesimplelogin

I have a FireBase db with a users store. I also use simple login email/pw. In the User store I save some extra info of a user - e.g. the lastlogin date. This is my workflow - from registering to logging in:

I register a user;
when registered it is *added* to the simple login email/pw sote;
I also add the registered user (includng the id returned from the simplelogin) in the users store. It is stored under a Firebase generated unique key.

I log in as that new user
When successful I get a user object from the simplelogin store:

```
email-"testuser1@test.com"
firebaseAuthToken-"eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGci...SoXkddR3A88vAkENCy5ilIk"
id-"46"
isTemporaryPassword-false
md5_hash-"6a4b6cb2045fd55f706eaebd6ab5d4f7"
provider-"password"
uid-"simplelogin:46"
```

Now I want to update the corresponding user in the User store - e.g. set the lastlogin key to now. But I only can update that user when I know the Firebase generated key it's under. How can I access that key?

The only other way to identify the user in the Users store is by retrieving all users in the Users store, looping through all of them and checking : does the current id key value match the id key value of the logged-in user. Looks a bit clumsy to me but I fear this is the only way I can do lookups with firebase?

Comment: Please don't add additional questions to other people's anwers, use comments or your original question instead.

Answer (score 1):

When you save a registered user you should save them by their uid rather than a generated id. This way when the user logs back in we'll user the uid to get the user from the users node.

```
var fbRef = new Firebase('https://<YOUR-FIREBASE>.firebaseio.com');
var auth = new FirebaseSimpleLogin(fbRef, function(error, user) {
  if (error) {
    console.error(error);
  } else if (user) {
    // when a user logs in we can update their lastLogin here
    // set the key to the uid for the user
    // this would look like: https://myapp.firebaseio.com/users/1
    fbRef.child('users').child(user.uid).update({
       lastLogin: Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP // the time they logged in
    });
  }
});

// here when we create a user we will set the key to the uid under the users node
auth.createUser(email, password, function(error, user) {
  // if there is no error
  if (!error) {
    // go to the users node, then set a location at the user's uid
    // this would look like: https://myapp.firebaseio.com/users/1
    fbRef.child('users').child(user.uid).set(user);
  }
});
```

As the users are created our users node will look like this:

[image: Users node]

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to 'save' the lastLogin value before overwriting it with the current timestamp (fbRef.child('users').child(user.uid).update({lastLogin: Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP // the time they logged in});)?I want a user to see when he logged in last time.

Comment: You can definitely save it somewhere, it just depends on what you want to do. Do you want to maintain a list of all the times they have logged in?

Comment: What I want is after the user authenticated succesfully to 1) retrieve the corresponding user from the Users store  - call it userData 2) save that userData.loginTimeStamp value to a $scope variable to display on the page 3) update the value of userData.loginTimeStamp to the current timestamp. You showed me how to do 3), I am not able to access the values of userData object by doing userData = usersRef.child(user.id); console.log(userData.loginTimestamp)

Comment: I also showed you how to do 1 and 2. If you update the answer and show me your code I can help you further.

Comment: Thanks, I found the answer to that last q as well.